# How would I change my program so the timer rests after the method is correct

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer

How would I reset the 30 seconds once the method is right, so far after each method is correct I abort the thread then start a new one in the next method and start that, but the console still closes after 30 seconds rather than resetting the timer?
I'm assuming that it's a stopwatch timer issue?

```
namespace Calculator
{

    class Program
    {

        static ThreadStart ThreadStart = new ThreadStart(Counter);
        static Thread Thread = new Thread(ThreadStart)
        {
            Priority = ThreadPriority.Highest
        };
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("INSTRUCTIONS - You have 30 seconds to answer each question correctly, once you get the question right the next question will appear," +
            "if you get a question wrong the console will display INCORRECT and you will have until the end of the 30 seconds to answer it correctly.");
            //These are the instructions
            Thread.Start();

            q1();
            q2();
        }

        static Stopwatch timer = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        static void Counter()
        {
            if (timer.ElapsedMilliseconds < 30000)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                Counter();
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Too late");

                Environment.Exit(0);
            }

        }

        static void q1() //Return type is a string as a string prompting the user will ask them to try again
        {
            Console.WriteLine("1+1"); //This is the question
            int answer = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());// Can't apply int to a readline, so convert the useres input to an int so you can apply an int variable

            if (answer == 2) //If the users input is equal to 2 
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Correct");//Tells the user that they are correct
                Thread.Abort();
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Try again");
                q1();
            }
        }
        static void q2() //Return type is a string as a string prompting the user will ask them to try again
        {
            Thread Threadq2 = new Thread(ThreadStart);
            Threadq2.Start();
            Console.WriteLine("2+2"); //This is the question
            int answer = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());// Can't apply int to a readline, so convert the useres input to an int so you can apply an int variable

            if (answer == 4) //If the users input is equal to 2 
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Correct");//Tells the user that they are correct
                Thread.Abort();
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Try again");
                q1();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you don't really have a need for a Thread here

Secondly, `Timer` is probably not what you are looking for, and you would seemingly find an easier solution in measuring times.

```
public static DateTime _starTime;

...

Console.WriteLine("INSTRUCTIONS - You have 30 seconds to answer each question correctly, once you get the question right the next question will appear," +
        "if you get a question wrong the console will display INCORRECT and you will have until the end of the 30 seconds to answer it correctly.");

_starTime = DateTime.Now();

...
```

then when you want to check (i.e after a user answered) you could do something like this

```
var seconds = DateTime.Now.Subtract(_starTime).TotalSeconds;

If(seconds > 30)
{
   // game over
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you put `timer.Restart();` at the beginning of your q1/q2 methods? That way the timer restarts each time you call them

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a `Timer` an set the interval at 30 seconds. On Elapsed event just close the console.

```
private static System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer(2000);
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            timer.Elapsed += Timer_Elapsed;
            timer.Start();

            // show instructions
            while (true)
            {
               string answer = Console.ReadLine();
                if (answer == "2") // check the answer somehow
                {
                    timer.Stop(); // and restart the timer
                    timer.Start();
                    // show next question
                }
            }

        }

        private static void Timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Too late");
            timer.Elapsed -= Timer_Elapsed;
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }
```